# Multiple UIWebView along with border in single view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm new to iOS and working with `UIWebView` as i have created two web searches in single view controller. But it is taking only one search i.e www.apple.com in below code, and border is not creating for two views.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0,500,350)];
[webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

CALayer *webViewLayer = webview.layer;
[webViewLayer setBorderColor: [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
[webViewLayer setBorderWidth: 2.75];  


NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
[webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];


webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 400,500,350)];
   [webview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSString *url2=@"http://www.apple.com";
NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
[webview loadRequest:nsrequest2];
[self.view addSubview:webview2];
[webview setScalesPageToFit:NO];

CALayer *webViewLayer2 = webview2.layer;
[webViewLayer2 setBorderColor: [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
[webViewLayer2 setBorderWidth: 2.75]; 

}
```